# Почему дескрипторы используются в качестве атрибутов класса, а не экземпляра?

Tags: python

Суть вопроса отражена в заголовке. Я знаю как определяются дескрипторы и для чего они нужны, суть в управляемых атрибутах. Знаю как реализовывать weakref-ссылки, чтобы при удалении объекта к которому привязан дескриптор, garbage collector отрабатывал правильно. Но не могу понять почему именно мы назначаем дескриптор в качестве атрибута класса, а не атрибута экземпляра.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/  не то ?

Comment: @Интик, я почитаю, и отвечу